# req is not readable after middleware used

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm attempting to secure an API endpoint of mine with passport running on node.js version 0.8.2.  The controller function I have looks something like this:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    console.log('Request readable? ' + req.readable);

    ... stream blob in req to create blob ...
};
```

This works great when there is no middleware to authenticate the incoming request and "Request readable? true" is printed to the console.

When I introduce the middleware to authenticate the incoming request, the req is not readable any longer in my controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the middleware?

Comment: sorry - its a passport-http-bearer Authorization check

Comment: Are you using the `bodyParser` middleware as well? That will read the request if you pass parameters (either in query string for GET or body for POST) and set `readable` to `false`.

Comment: I'm using bodyParser but it hasn't interfered previously - basically, I am going from this: app.post(config.api_prefix + 'v1/blobs', controllers.blobs.create); to this: app.post(config.api_prefix + 'v1/blobs', middleware.authenticateRequest, controllers.blobs.create);
where the first works and the second doesn't.

Comment: Ordering middlewares is important. Check this with the middlewares you're using. Example, `.compress` middleware should not be used before `.flash`, `.bodyParser` or `.session`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening in this case is that I was making a call to fetch the accessToken from the database asynchronously and in this gap the stream when unreadable:

```
// req.readable == true here

auth(req, res, function(err) {
    // req.readable == false here
```

What you need to do in this situation is pause and resume the request stream:

```
// req.readable == true here

req.pause();
auth(req, res, function(err) {
    req.resume();
    // req.readable == true here
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem. The solution for me was to upgrade node to >0.10.